# How to get a file from local Git repository to an Eclipse workspace based on version

Tags: eclipse, egit

I have a file with different versions in my local git repository.I need to get a particular version which is the same as the file in the local eclipse workspace.

Answer (score 0):

From Project explorer, select your file. Switch to (or open) History view. Select the revision you are interested in, right click and choose Open.

Answer (score 0):

I have got this by using "git.checkout().setName(label);"(git is instance of git repository)in eclipse RCP.Thanks @Mari